# Why can I see a table in user_tables but can't find it in dba_tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have created a table with the "create table as (select.....)" statement by the user called "X", which is a copy of another table, from a user called "Y".

When I list all the tables from dba_tables, owned by X, there isn't anything, but if I write "select tablespace_name, table_name from user_tables;" I can see the new tabble owned by me (the X user).

Comment: Can you run `select sys_context('userenv','current_user'), user from dual` and confirm that both the returned users are the same and are `X`? It's possible that though you've logged into `X` you're not actually looking at the data from `X`.

Comment: I run it, and yes, they are the same. Both X.

Comment: Do not wrap object names in double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I write the X user's name with different case letters, but in search, I must write it all in upper case letters.